# How to map the text_fields to Hash objects fields in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Please refer to code.

```
    <%= form_tag(:action => "create_user", :method => "post") do%>
<p><label for="first_name">First Name</label>:
    <%= text_field 'json_parsed', 'first_name') %></p>
<p><label for="middle_name">Middle Name</label>:
    <%= text_field 'json_parsed', 'middle_name') %></p>
<p><label for="last_name">Last Name</label>:
    <%= text_field 'json_parsed', 'last_name') %></p>
    <% @contact = @json_parsed["contact"] %>
<p><label for="last_name">Email</label>:
    <%= text_field 'contact','email']) %></p>
<p><label for="last_name">Phone</label>:
    <%= text_field 'contact', 'phone_no') %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

here, '`json_parsed`' is the hash object which i have got after `json_decode`. `first_name/middle_name/etc`. are all fields in that hash object. Now i want to get those values in text_field. But it is giving error "undefined method '`first_name`' for hash".

How can i show those values in hash directly into text_field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use text_field for hash objects. It can be used for model objects(objects which have a method with the name you call eg. `@json_parsed` should have a method first_name such that we can call `@json_parsed.first_name`). For hash, we cannot call it like that. So, you should either use text_field_tag like this

```
<%=text_field_tag 'json_parsed[first_name]', :value => @json_parsed["first_name"]%>
```

or you should convert the hash into ruby class object with the corresponding method names, using Hashit.

```
class Hashit
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |k,v|
      v = Hashit.new(v) if v.is_a?(Hash)
      self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) ## create and initialize an instance variable for this key/value pair
      self.class.send(:define_method, k, proc{self.instance_variable_get("@#{k}")}) ## create the getter that returns the instance variable
      self.class.send(:define_method, "#{k}=", proc{|v| self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)}) ## create the setter that sets the instance variable
    end
  end
end
```

and use it to make the object,

```
@json_parsed = Hashit.new(json_parsed_hash)
```

and use it in the views as you just did. For more details on Hashit, refer this [link](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/1/6/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-a-class-object/).

For your contact hash, you should use it like this

```
<p><label for="last_name">Email</label>:
<%= fields_for @json_parsed.contact do |p|%
    <%= p.text_field 'email'%></p>
<p><label for="last_name">Phone</label>:
    <%= p.text_field 'phone_no') %></p>
```

Perhaps, you should use it like this in the views

```
<% form_for :json_parsed, :url => {:action => "create_user"} do |f| %>
<p><label for="first_name">First Name</label>:
    <%= f.text_field 'first_name' %></p>
<p><label for="middle_name">Middle Name</label>:
    <%= f.text_field 'middle_name' %></p>
<p><label for="last_name">Last Name</label>:
    <%= f.text_field 'last_name' %></p>
    <% f.fields_for 'contact' do |p| %>
<p><label for="last_name">Email</label>:
    <%= p.text_field 'email' %></p>
<p><label for="last_name">Phone</label>:
    <%= p.text_field 'phone_no' %></p>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: see my hash object contains:
{"first_name"=>"Aashish", "middle_name"=>"Shrikant", "last_name"=>"Pathak", "contact"=>{"email"=>"aashish@gslab.com", "phone_no"=>"9922582272"}, "profile"=>{
"age"=>"22", "ht"=>"175", "wt"=>"67"}}

i have tried to convert it to class object as you said. But it is giving error as 'undefined method [] in Hashit'

Comment: If you see to the hash object, it is nested. Basically this is what i got from one webservice. Now i want to send same kind of structure back to some other webservice for saving new data.

Comment: you shoud edit your `<% @contact = @json_parsed["contact"] %>` line to `<% @contact = @json_parsed.contact] %>` and also use `fields_for` for contact. I will edit my answer.

Comment: You will get same kind of structure if you call params[:json_parsed] on submitting this form.

Comment: Actually fields_for require model object and i don't have it. It will not work. But yeah your first solution did work for me. thanks for that:)

Comment: oh..yes..sorry...then u should try the nested attributes solution he has said in the comments of the link..I have updated the code for Hashit with it.

Comment: Only a line `v = Hashit.new(v) if v.is_a?(Hash)` is added to make any hash inside also to object.

Comment: @aashish..If it solved your problem, mark the checkmark near the question to accept the answer.